# Mask URL part while proxying Tomcat webapp through Nginx

Tags: nginx, rewrite, url, web-applications, mask

I've got the webbapp at the server 1.1.1.1:8080/AppName/
Now I need to hide port and AppName dir URL part.
So I installed Nginx on server 2.2.2.2 with virthost name test.com.

Here is the virthost config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name test.com;


    location / {

    proxy_pass http://1.1.1.1:8080/;

    }
}
```

Port is hided but how can I mask out AppName? Now I run site as http://test.com/AppName/ but need http://test.com/

The following doesn't make success (too many redirects fail):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name test.com;


    location / {

    proxy_pass http://1.1.1.1:8080/;
    rewrite ^/(.*) http://test.com/AppName/$1 break;

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

BTW if you sujest how to reach that wih Apache+mod_proxy I would apreciate much too.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/253023/mapping-hudson-to-a-subdomain-through-nginx-proxying

Answer (score 0):

How about proxy_pass http://tomcat:port/appname/?

Comment: No way. I get 404 Not Fount at the next response. But don't know exactly how to trace that and understand what's going on.